# can I use std::copy to copy into stringstream

Tags: c++, stl

I recently had the case where I wanted to take the raw bytes of an `int64_t` value into a string stream.  In C++17 I could do the following:

```
uint64_t val = 1984;
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << "the byte value is " << std::string_view(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(decltype(val)));
```

and bob's your uncle.  But I need to do it with C++98, or maybe C++11.  I thought to do the following:

```
std::copy(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tmp_time),
          reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tmp_time) + sizeof tmp_time,
          std::back_inserter(sstr));
```

but g++ complains when instantiating the `back_inserter` that there is no type named `value_type` in a `basic_stringstream`.

Can I not `std::copy` into a `stringstream` object?  How do I go about doing it?  Note the above is a trivialized example, and I'm reluctant to give up on the streaming semantics as they are very tidy in the real context.

Comment: `std::back_inserter` is for containers that provide the `push_back()` function. Have you tried to use a `general inserter` ? The error `no type named value_type` comes from the fact that the compiler cannot find the appropriate `iterator_tag`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::copy(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tmp_time),
          reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&tmp_time) + sizeof tmp_time,
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss, " "));
```

You need to decide what type to use with it though. I am using `int` to print values as signed integers and use one space as a delimeter. You may choose something else depending on what you want to achieve.

Using `std::back_inserter` does not work with streams, because its purpose is to operate on containers. It creates `std::back_inserter_iterator` which calls `push_back` member function on the passed container. It also assumes that `Container` has member types `value_type`, `const_reference` and others (you check how they are used [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator/operator%3D)).

Here an example: iterator returned by `std::back_inserter` has `operator=` defined like this:

```
back_insert_iterator<Container> &operator=(typename Container::value_type &&value);
```

So because `std::stringstream` does not defined `value_type`, compilation fails.

Comment: That works (will accept when the time limit expires).  Extra gratitude if you can explain my failure in reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `std::copy()`, or any other algorithm. You can use the stream's own [`write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) method instead, eg:

```
uint64_t val = 1984;
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << "the byte value is ";
sstr.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
```